# Connect via ssh to CF - Error

Tags: ssh, ibm-cloud, remote-debugging, cloud-foundry

I need to debug my application , we are using version 2.65 (Diego) 
.
I use the following wiki
http://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html

while running `cf ssh myapp` via cli 
nothing happens , what should I do in order

```
1. To see the container FS
2. To be able to debug it ?
```

The application was deployed successfully to CF.
Im using nodejs app.
all other commands are working well.

When I run the command  `cf ssh myapp` I got this error after two minutes :

```
FAILED
Error opening SSH connection: dial tcp 52.23.201.1:2277: getsockopt: operation timed out
```

Comment: Does it hang or what? cf ssh works great for me, bluemix nodejs apps.  I end up in a terminal where I can look at files/logs/top etc.  I run it from a windows cmd prompt. I didn't do anything to enable it beyond switching to diego.

Comment: @amadain - when running it nothing happen , it looks like that hang and not sure how to proceed ...any idea what it can be since all the cf other commands are working as expected .....

Comment: Your shell?  I had to stop using powershell for it, use it from an administrator cmd shell now.  It wasn't hanging though.

Comment: @amadain - I use mac book pro built in terminal ...\

Comment: Maybe try other apps, in case it's a problem with just one. Or a firewall could be blocking it I guess?  It's weird being on Windows lately.  After centuries of suffering my life is now generally easier than all the linux and mac people.

Comment: @amadain - I've try it already in other running app without any success, maybe there is a way to indetify it ? btw Im under a corporate proxy but all the cli commands are working like cf scale , cf apps,services etc . do you think its related to proxy ,if yes how can I overcome this ?

Comment: sorry, no idea. I just use it and love it but not an expert on it.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can connect, `dial tcp 52.23.201.1:2277: getsockopt: operation timed out`.  Port 2277 seems odd, usually it's 2222, but your operator could have changed that.  I believe the cli get's this info from the `/v2/info` end point.  You could run `cf curl /v2/info` to confirm what the platform is exposing.  I would also suggest trying from another network, one that's not behind a corporate firewall.  If that works, then you've limited the problem to the firewall and you can look for a solution to that problem.  I don't know off hand how to work around that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a platform issue using non-standard ssh port.

You can find a bit more ssh access manual steps/troubleshooting tips on https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/ssh-apps.html

If you believe it is a instance issue, you can download a copy of droplet/fs using api, more on https://apidocs.cloudfoundry.org/213/apps/downloads_the_staged_droplet_for_an_app.html